# How to get a dynamic library to access network permissions in framework layer?

Tags: android, android-ndk, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

We developed an algorithm for sound processing, which was packaged into an Android dynamic library using Android ndk. Our customers will integrate it into the android framework layer. We used curl to make a network request to verify the sdk license. But we found that the dynamic library did not have access to the network. Since it is in the framework layer, there is no activity, there is no way to apply for internet permission through the Android Manifest. What do I need to do?

Comment: This library you speak of, is it .jar .aar, or something else? Also, I believe it would be used inside an _application_, right?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The library is .so.Our customers integrate it into the media server in the Android rom. So this library does not have a corresponding app.